# Icon da fonte não mostra

Tags: visual-studio, iis, font, icons

Eu criei uma fonte usando o app Inkscape. e depois converti em um site que não me recordo no momento...
enquanto eu estou usando essa fonte no visual studio, a fonte mostra perfeitamente, como mostra na imagem a seguir:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém quando eu publico o projeto, e rodo ele no IIS local, ele não mostra o icone, apenas a letra. como mostra na imagem a seguir:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguém sabe como eu posso fazer para mostrar o icone, como na primeira imagem?

esse é o CSS, usando:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Smc';
    src: url('../fonts/ismc.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/ismc.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/ismc.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/ismc.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/ismc.svg') format('svg');
    src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/ismc.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/ismc.ttf') format('truetype');
}

.smc:before {
    content: 'S'
}

.smc:before {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: 'Smc';
    font-style: normal;
    color: #114876;
}
```

Comment: já viu se a publicação engloba todos os ficheiros corretamente?

Comment: Já sim.. inclusive, mudei alguns arquivos de pastas, para testar, e mesmo assim, ainda não aparece.

Comment: Já tentou apagar tudo da publicação e publicar novamente, sem nenhum ficheiro aberto em outro processo?

Comment: Não,. isso ainda não...

Comment: tente e diga se resolvou ;)

Comment: cara, eu consegui.... era burrice minha.... o css, está em uma pasta chamada Css. dentro da pasta, eu tenho o estilo.css e uma pasta com as fontes, o problema era que eu estava chamando da seguinte maneira.. 
 `../pasta/fonte.extensão`, porém era só `pasta/fonte.extensão`

Comment: Ainda bem que conseguiu, boa continuação de desenvolvimento